# Use done button to close my custom keyboard

Tags: java, android, ime, android-input-method

I am making a custom keyboard for android in android studio and i have almost implemented all the basic functionalities required for a basic keyboard but I am struggling to figure out how to close my keyboard when I press the done key in the bottom right corner.

Mostly all text box in android application contains an imeOption specifing the action the done key to perform for eg `android:imeOptions="actionGo"` is used in google chrome url bar and to make chrome search on done key i had to use `inputConnection.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));` to make it work and for `android:imeOptions="actionNone"` `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"` this worked fine `inputConnection.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));` but I can't figure out what should I do for `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` and `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the placement of a view. As if it's a edit text and its the last view in the view hierarchy then you can set its view's android:imeOptions="actionDone". This will hide the keyboard. And android:imeOptions="actionNext" if used in any view then it will move focus to next edit text if there's any.

I hope i understood your question. If not please elaborate. I would love to help.

Comment: Yeah that's how they work and those actions (closing the keyboard and changing focus to next view) is executed by a key called enter or done key which is located on the bottom right corner of any typical keyboard. My problem here was that i am creating my own "Custom keyboard" which should perform this action like closing the keyboard and changing focus to next view with respect to the corresponding view but i can't make that work in my "Custom Keyboard"

Comment: @RajeshNadar Can you please share your code? because it would be easy that way to recognize the issue.

Comment: I am using `InputMethodService` for my keyboard and `OnKeyboardActionListener` for monitering the inputs. I am using `onKey` function to check which key is press and using the inputConnection object to perform task on the edittext this is how it is done 

`public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
        if (inputConnection != null) {
            switch (primaryCode) {
                case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:`

Comment: @RajeshNadar im not able to undestand your question. If you can give me code that i can run directly and troubleshoot then it would be better

Comment: How can I share my project to you?

Comment: Post code here or just put it on github and share the link.